# How to reduce the ODE to first order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reduction-of-order-ode

How to reduce the following O.D.E. into first order?

> $$(vv_{xxx}-v_{x}v_{xx})g^2 + v^3 v_x = 0, \tag{1}$$ where $v=v(x)$ and $v_{x}$ is the derivative w.r.t $x$, $g$ is a constant. After integration, equation (1) can be written as $$(vv_{xx}-v_{x}^2)g^2+\frac{v^4}{4} - c=0, \tag{2}$$ where $c$ is an integration constant. How to integrate further to get a first order O.D.E.?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Is the task really to find a series of integrations, or to transform the equation into a first-order system as preparation for a numerical solution?

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann, to transform the equation into a first-order

Answer (score 3):

$$(vv_{xxx}-v_{x}v_{xx})g^2 + v^3 v_x = 0, \tag{1}$$
$$\left(\dfrac {v_{xx}}v \right)'g^2 + \dfrac 12 (v^2)' = 0$$
$$\dfrac {v_{xx}}vg^2 + \dfrac 12 v^2 = C$$
Mutiply by $2v_xv$:
$$ 2{v_xv_{xx}}g^2 + v_xv^3 = 2Cv_xv$$
Integrate.
$$ (v_{x})^2g^2 +\dfrac 14 v^4 = C_1v^2+C_2$$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$ v_{xx}=\frac{dv_x}{dx}=\frac{dv_x}{dv}\frac{dv}{dx}=v_x\frac{dv_x}{dv}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{dv_x^2}{dv}$$
Thus the equation (2) can be written as
$$(\frac{1}{2}v\frac{dv_x^2}{dv}-v_x^2)g^2+\frac{v^2}{4}-c=0$$
which is a first order ODE about $v_x^2(v)$ and can be solved easily.

Comment: Can we reduce it to first order O.D.E where independent variable would be $x$?

Comment: We can solve the above ODE of $ v_x^2(v)$ and get $ v_x^2=c_1 v^2-c^2-\frac{1}{2}v^2 ln(v)$ ($c_1 $is an integration constant),which is a first order ODE of independent variable x

Answer (score 1):

The equation becomes singular, formally or even actually, for $v=0$. Thus outside this plane we can set, following along the structure that you already found, $v_x=av$. Then $v_{xx}=a_xv+av_x=(a_x+a^2)v=bv$ and
$$
vv_{xxx}-v_xv_{xx}=v^2(b_x+ab-ab)
$$
and the equation in total now reads
$$
g^2b_x+av^2=0
$$
This in total can be written as first-order system
\begin{align}
v_x&=av\\
a_x&=b-a^2\\
b_x&=-\frac{av^2}{g^2}
\end{align}

---

Of course you can also follow along the usual derivatives array and set $V=(v,v_x,v_{xx})$ and replace the third derivative in $V_x=(v_x,v_{xx},v_{xxx})$ via the given ODE.